# using python i wan inside function for pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, if-statement

Am having a dataframe,need to implement

every month I will be running this script so automatically it will pick based on extracted date

```
Input Dataframe

client_id      expo_value          value           cal_value      extracted_date
1                   126             30                 27.06       08/2022
2                   135             60                 36.18       08/2022
3                   144             120                 45         08/2022 
4                   162             30                 54.09       08/2022
5                   153             90                 63.63       08/2022
6                   181             120                 72.9       08/2022


Input Dataframe

client_id      expo_value          value           cal_value      extracted_date  Output_Value
1                   126             30                 27.06       08/2022          126+26.18 = 152.18
2                   135             60                 36.18       08/2022         261.29+70.02 = 331.31
3                   144             120                 45         08/2022         557.4+174.19 = 731.59
4                   162             30                 54.09       08/2022         156.7+ 52.34 = 209.04  
5                   153             90                 63.63       08/2022         444.19+ 182.9 =627.09
6                   181             120                 72.9       08/2022         700.64+282.19=982.83
```

I want to `implement 31 days/30 days/28 days` inside the below function & i tried manually `entering the number 31(days)` for calculation but it should `automatically should pick` based on which month has how many days

```
def month_data(data):
if (data['value'] <=30).any():
    return data['expo_value'] *30/ 31(days) + data['cal_value'] * 45/ 31(days)
  
elif (data['value'] <=60).any():
    return data['expo_value'] *60/ 31(days) + data['cal_value'] * 90/31(days)

elif (data['value'] <=90).any():
    return data['expo_value'] *100/31(days) + data['cal_value'] * 120/ 31(days)
    
else (data['value'] <=120).any():
    return np.nan
```

Comment: have a look at the MonthEnd offset https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.tseries.offsets.MonthEnd.html#pandas.tseries.offsets.MonthEnd

Answer (score 3):

Let me see if I understood you correctly. I tried to reproduce a small subset of your dataframe (you should do this next time you post something). The answer is as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
import calendar

# I'll make a subset dataframe based on your example
data = [[30, '02/2022'], [60, '08/2022']]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['value', 'extracted_date'])

# First, turn the extracted_date column into a correct date format
date_correct_format = [datetime.strptime(i, '%m/%Y') for i in df['extracted_date']]

# Second, calculate the number of days per month
num_days = [calendar.monthrange(i.year, i.month)[1] for i in date_correct_format]
num_days
```